# scala map collect equivalent to groovy map collect

Tags: scala, groovy

I want list of all values for particular key in a nested map. I have super beautiful example in groovy as below.

```
class HashTableExperiment {

    static def retailPackages = [
            "package1": [
                    "items"       : ["white shirt", "blue pants", "blue shirt"],
                    "shippingDate": new Date(2016, 10, 28)
            ],
            "package2": [
                    "items"       : ["blue shirt", "brown pants", "blue converse"],
                    "shippingDate": new Date(2016, 11, 23)
            ]
    ]

    static def itemInventory() {
        retailPackages.entrySet().collect {it.value.items}.flatten()
    }

    static def main(String[] args) {
        itemInventory().each {
            println(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
white shirt
blue pants
blue shirt
blue shirt
brown pants
blue converse
```

I want this implementation in scala, couldn't do it naturally like in groovy.

```
object MapExperiment {

  val retailPackages = Map(
    "package1" -> Map(
      "items" -> List("white shirt", "blue pants", ""),
      "shippingDate" -> new Date(2016, 10, 28)
    ),
    "package2" -> Map(
      "items" -> List("blue shirt", "brown pants", "blue converse"),
      "shippingDate" -> new Date(2016, 11, 23)
    )
  )

  def itemInventory(): Unit = {
    val items = retailPackages.map(p => p._2).map(it => it("items"))
    items.flatten
  }
}
```

I get the following compile error in flatten

```
Error:(25, 11) No implicit view available from java.io.Serializable => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
    items.flatten
          ^
```

Also, my assumption was type of `items` variable should be `List[List[String]]`, nope, scala compiler shouts it should be `Iterable[Serializable]`. At least, `Iterable[Iterable[String]]` makes sense, but where does Serializable come from??

When I give it a type,

```
val items : Iterable[Serializable] = retailPackages.map(p => p._2).map(it => it("items"))
```

It says `Iterable[Serializable] doesn't conform to Iterable[Serializable]`

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to use tuples so that you have a `Map[String, (List[String], Date)]`. As it stands you are losing all your type information with `Map[String, Map[Any]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can coerce the items from `Serializable` to `List[String]`:

```
@ MapExperiment.retailPackages("package1")("items")
res11: Object with java.io.Serializable = List(white shirt, blue pants, )

@ MapExperiment.retailPackages("package1")("items").asInstanceOf[List[String]]
res12: List[String] = List("white shirt", "blue pants", "")
```

Then the `flatten` works:

```
@ MapExperiment.retailPackages map { _._2 } map { _("items").asInstanceOf[List[String]] } flatten
res13: collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List("white shirt", "blue pants", "", "blue shirt", "brown pants", "blue converse")
```

or in a single map:

```
@ MapExperiment.retailPackages map { _._2("items").asInstanceOf[List[String]] } flatten
res14: collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List("white shirt", "blue pants", "", "blue shirt", "brown pants", "blue converse")
```

Comment: It feels weird to cast `retailPackages map { _._2("items")` to `List[String]`. Since `"items"` key has `List` of `String`, compiler should've figured it as `List[String]` by itself, just like what groovy compiler does.

Comment: @PrayagUpd It sure does, but the issue is that it's a `Map[String, Serializable]` so the RHS can only be a Serializable and needs to be re-cast.

Comment: @PrayagUpd This bites me often, trying to parse JSON in scala is more awkward than it needs to be (IMO).

Comment: groovy looks so much natural to me than scala so far. Whenever I code in scala, my code always looks ugly, maybe I might be missing something.

Comment: @PrayagUpd With this kind of example it could be worth making a Package case class for (item, shippingDate) pairs, that way they can be typed and implicits should help clean up the code. mixed datatypes in maps don't work out that well.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused the **retailPackages** is mixed type:

```
Map(
  String -> Map (
    String -> List,
    String -> Date
  )
)
```

so when map the "items", it can't infer the *items* type, you can use `case` to match the *items* type:

```
retailPackages.map(i => i._2("items")).flatMap{case l: List[String] => l}
```

Suggestion is: use case class for your element, like:

```
case class MyObject(items: List[String], shippingDate: Date)
val retailPackages = Map(
    "package1" -> MyObject(List("white shirt", "blue pants", ""), new Date(2016, 10, 28))
      ,
    "package2" -> MyObject(List("blue shirt", "brown pants", "blue converse"),new Date(2016, 11, 23))
)
retailPackages.flatMap(i => i._2.items)
```